# What's the proper way to iteratively grab a value from an array when the key is a string?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export some lists from Sharepoint into a CSV file. My goal is to make a single function that is flexible enough to take a List name, identifier for the CSV file, and a list of FieldValues to export, and then produce a CSV file. Here's what I have so far:

```
function getTableData($_ctx, [string]$_colName)
{
    $list = $_ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("$_colName")

    $camlQuery = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery(100)
    $colItems = $list.GetItems($camlQuery)
    $_ctx.Load($colItems)
    $_ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    return $colItems
}

# More will go into this array, but for now a single entry is sufficient for testing purposes
$mstLists = @("GroupMst", "Groups", @("Title", "GroupCode"))

$cols = @()
foreach($col in $mstLists[0][2])
{
    $cols += @{Name=$col;expression={$_[$col];}}
}
$cols

# Grab all items from a list
getListData $ctx $mstLists[0][0] |
%{ select-object -input $_ -prop $cols } |
    Export-Csv -Path ($export_path + '\' + $current_date + '_' + $mstLists[0][1] + '.csv') -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem I'm having is in the loop that populates $cols. Basically, each item needs to look like `@{Name="Title";expression={$_["Title"];}}` in order for `select-object` in the `ForEach` to grab the proper fields from the List. Unfortunately `$cols` ends up being looking like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
expression                     $_[$col];
Name                           Title
expression                     $_[$col];
Name                           GroupCode
```

Which (somehow) produces a CSV file that looks like this:

```
"Title","GroupCode"
"LA","LA"
"NY","NY"
"TK","TK"
```

When the output needs to look like this:

```
"Title","GroupCode"
"Los Angeles","LA"
"New York","NY"
"Tokyo","TK"
```

I know the field names are correct - if I hardcode them in like so...

```
# Grab all items from a list
getListData $ctx $mstLists[0][0] |
%{ select-object -input $_ -prop `
@{Name="Title";expression={$_["Title"];}}, `
@{Name='GroupCode';expression={$_["GroupCode"];}}; } |
    Export-Csv -Path ($export_path + '\' + $current_date + '_' + $mstLists[0][1] + '.csv') -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

...then I get the desired CSV output. I just can't figure out how to get `$_[$col]` to instead return `$_["Title"]`

Comment: In the problem loop, what is $mstLists[0][2] meant to refer to? In fact it is pulling the first item from the array ("GroupMST") and extracting the 3rd character ("o"). Suspect this is not what is intended.

Comment: @andyb `$mstList` will eventually contain multiple items that I'll iterate through. Each item will follow the format of `@("ListName", "CSVFileID", @("Field1", "Field2", "Etc..."))`, so @mstLists[0][2] refers to the list of fields in the first item in the array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the $mstLists[0][2] meant to refer to, but the following code seems to give what you are after...

```
$mstLists = @("GroupMst", "Groups", @("Title", "GroupCode"))

$cols = @()
foreach($col in $mstLists[2])
{
    $cols += @{Name=$col; Expression = [scriptblock]::Create('$_["{0}"]' -f $col)}
}
$cols
```

which gives...

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                      
Name                           Title                                                                                                                                                      
Expression                     $_["Title"]                                                                                                                                                
Name                           GroupCode                                                                                                                                                  
Expression                     $_["GroupCode"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your response to andyb in the comments, you say that each item of the array will follow the format

```
@("ListName", "CSVFileID", @("Field1", "Field2", "Etc..."))
```

and that `$mstLists[0][2]` "refers to the list of fields in the first item in the array."

The problem is that it *doesn't* refer to the list of fields in the first item of the array, because the first item of the array isn't a list of anything, it's the string `GroupMst`. When you index into a string, you get the character indicated by the index. Since **$mstLists[0]** is a string, **$mstLists[0][2]** returns the third character of that string, which is `o`.

I suppose you were expecting that the @ operator would make the array in the parentheses a single item, which becomes the first element of **$mstLists**? It doesn't. All the @ does is ensure that the expression in the parentheses is evaluated as an array rather than a scalar. So, with `$a = ('string')`, **$a** is a string, whereas with `$a = @('string')`, **$a** is an array with a single string element.

However, since `("GroupMst", "Groups", @("Title", "GroupCode"))` evaluates to an array anyway, putting an @ in front of it is redundant. Either way you're still assigning a literal array to the variable. **$mstLists** is an array of three elements:

- Element 0 is the string `GroupMst`
- Element 1 is the string `Groups`
- Element 2 is an array of the strings `Title` and `GroupCode`

What you want to do is use `,` as a unary operator:

```
$mstLists = , ("GroupMst", "Groups", @("Title", "GroupCode"))
```

Now **$mstLists** is an array of a single item whose value is the array described in the bulleted list above, and `$mstLists[0][2]` evaluates to an array of the strings `Title` and `GroupCode`, as you were expecting.

Note that `,` works as a unary or binary operator that returns an array of the operands. To return a single-element array, you use it as a unary operator in front of that element. If you have multiple literal arrays that you want to assign to **mstLists**, you only need commas between them, not the one in front:

```
$mstLists = ("ListName", "CSVFileID", @("Field1", "Field2", "Etc...")), ("ListName2", "CSVFileID2", @("Field1", "Field2", "Etc..."))
```

That addresses the main problem. That still won't quite give you what you want, because **$col** won't get interpolated in the **Expression** scriptblock, so **Expression** will always be literally `$_[$col]`. However, in order to figure out how to do what you actually want to do, it would be helpful to see a sample of the contents of **$ctx**.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the use of @, I was getting confused as to when I needed to preface a simple or associate array with it. It's nice to know that an array is assumed if there are multiple values within parentheses. If $mstLists contains multiple items, do I need to play a comma in front of each item when I add them?

Comment: You still need commas, but if there are multiple items then you don't need a comma in front of the first. I actually was going to mention that in my answer but forgot. I'll add it now.